# Importing contacts into Exchange personal contact folders

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

My company is currently moving from Mirapoint to Exchange and we want to be able to transfer over users personal contacts into Exchange.

We are able to export contact information just fine, but unfortunately all the methods I have found for importing contacts into Exchange have been for importing into global mail contacts and not into specific users contact folders.

Has anyone come across a way to do this, preferably in PowerShell?

Thank you.

Comment: What type of file is the Mirapoint contacts exported to?

Comment: @MichaelBurns Knew I left something out, we currently have the data as a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link worked fantastically for our situation: 
http://www.stevieg.org/2010/07/using-powershell-to-import-contacts-into-exchange-and-outlook-live/

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the contacts to PSTs from Mirapoint then you can use the [Exchange Management Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245704%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) you can import contacts to a mailbox using the commandlet 'Import-Mailbox'

```
Import-Mailbox -Identity john.smith@company.com -PSTFolderPath C:\PSTFiles\john.pst -IncludeFolders "\Contacts"
```

More Examples: [How to Import Mailbox Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691363%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)